# Create a Qt library to be used in a non-Qt application

Tags: qt

I created a Qt static library following the instruction here: 
http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

Then I tried to link the library with my own (non-Qt) application, and GCC complained about undefined references. Examining the library content using Linux `nm` utilty I found the function I intend to call has cryptic letters added before and after it.

Reading the instruction from the instruction link more closely, it suggests that I need to use use an import define so the right Qt macro can be called to import the function (which I assume renames the function to match the naming scheme in the library). But I don't really want to introduce Qt dependency in my main application.

What I really want to do is to build a UI frontend library with Qt, and my main application will simply link to it without having any Qt dependency. Is this possible? Or am I using Qt in an unintended manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're running into C++ namespace mangling.  Try adding an 'extern "C" {}' block around your libraries export.

The main point of the QLibrary::resolve function is to provide an abstraction layer so you don't have to worry about the win32 command or the linux command for resolving a symbol.  It shouldn't be necessary to use a library created with Qt.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Do you have any recommended reading materials on intermixing C/C++, or C++ for C programmer? I come from a C background, and am not as familiar with C++.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'd say try to learn the standard, or at least the parts you're using, and look at example code.  http://cplusplus.com/ and MDSN are pretty good documentation.